Trying to spin up aws_wafv2_rule_group and getting "Error: creating WAFv2 RuleGroup"
I am trying to spin up a aws_wafv2_rule_group resource in AWS to be used on a cloudfront instance.  This will be an IPset rule that only allows requests from IPs on the list.
Here is the code:
resource "aws_wafv2_ip_set" "ip_whitelist" {
  name               = "${var.waf_type}-${var.team_name}-${var.environment}-ipset"
  scope              = "CLOUDFRONT"
  ip_address_version = "IPV4"
  addresses          = var.micro_frontend_ip_address_whitelist
}

resource "aws_wafv2_rule_group" "ip_whitelist" {
  name        = "${var.waf_type}-${var.team_name}-${var.environment}-waf-rule-group"
  description = "This rule group contains whitelist rules for the micro-frontends."
  scope       = "CLOUDFRONT"
  capacity    = 1

  rule {
    name     = "${var.waf_type}-${var.team_name}-${var.environment}-whitelist-rule"
    priority = 0

    action {
      block {}
    }

    statement {
      or_statement {
        statement {
          ip_set_reference_statement {
            arn = aws_wafv2_ip_set.ip_whitelist.arn
          }
        }
      }
    }

    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
      metric_name                = "${var.waf_type}-${var.team_name}-${var.environment}-waf-rule-group"
      sampled_requests_enabled   = false
    }
  }

  visibility_config {
    cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
    metric_name                = "${var.waf_type}-${var.team_name}-${var.environment}-waf-rule-group"
    sampled_requests_enabled   = false
  }
}

When running this, I get the following error in Terraform:
│ Error: creating WAFv2 RuleGroup (micro-frontend-foundation-staging-waf-rule-group): operation error WAFV2: CreateRuleGroup, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 4c6f81b8-cd88-44a7-b36c-78cb95ea369e, WAFInvalidParameterException: Error reason: You haven't met a minimum requirement for a threshold setting. Examples include a rule group capacity setting that's too low and an OR statement with only one nested statement., field: OR_STATEMENT, parameter: OrStatement
│ 
│   with module.aws.module.environments.module.staging.module.waf.module.micro-frontend[0].aws_wafv2_rule_group.ip_whitelist,
│   on .terraform/modules/aws.environments.staging.waf/micro-frontend/rule_group.tf line 8, in resource "aws_wafv2_rule_group" "ip_whitelist":
│    8: resource "aws_wafv2_rule_group" "ip_whitelist" {

I have tried changing the capacity to 500 to see if that was the issue.  That did not do the trick so I believe it is something to do with the Terraform.  However, when I look at examples on the terraform documentation for this resources, the code reflects what is shown.  What am I missing here?

or_statement applies a logical OR to two statements but you only provided 1 statement to or_statement.

Understood.  I just fixed that and it is working thanks!
